# vue.js passing data from parent single file component to child

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

Using single file architecture I'm trying to pass data (an object) from a parent component to a child:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <app-header app-content={{app_content}}></app-header>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import appHeader from './components/appHeader'
import {content} from './content/content.js'

export default {
  components: {
    appHeader
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      app_content: content
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**appHeader.vue**

```
<template>
  <header id="header">
    <h1>{{ app_content }}</h1>
  </header>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => {
    return {
      // nothing
    }
  },
  props: ['app_content'],
  created: () => {
    console.log(app_content) // undefined
  }
}
</script>
```

Seems to be such a trivial task and probably the solution is quite simple. Thanks for any advice :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there.

In order to send the `app_content` variable from App.vue to the child component you have to pass it as an attribute in the template like so:

```
<app-header :app-content="app_content"></app-header>
```

Now, in order to get the `:app-component` property inside appHeader.vue you will have to rename your prop from `app_component` to `appComponent` (this is Vue's convention of passing properties).
Finally, to print it inside child's template just change to: `{{ appContent }}`

Comment: Thank you but sadly, it still doesn't render in the child component ...

Comment: Can you do a `console.log` in both components, on the `ready()` method and make sure that `this.app_content ` actually contains something?

Comment: I get "undefined" even for "this" alone, in both components' ready() method

Comment: ...although the data shows in the rendered html property as [Object object]

Comment: Try changing the variable to `appContent` in appHeader.vue, so it will be `props: ['appContent']` and {{ appContent }} and also, in App.vue from `app-content={{app_content}} ` to `:app-content="app_content" ` as in my first post.

Comment: Okay, it works now. This kebab-case to camel-case conversion going on in vue.js is quite confusing to me I have to admit... thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please post a new answer with a short explanation on why this is so? For future reference and so I can set the thread as answered